# Solidity - Check if an index exists in contract A from Contract B

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I have two contracts called A and B. I defined an array variable in contract A. I want to check if an index exists or not from contract B.

**A.sol**

```
contract A {
    SomeStruct[] private myArray;
    /// @notice Check if an index exists
    function isIndexExists(uint256 index) public view returns (bool) {
      if (myArray[index].isExist) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

**B.sol**

```
contract B is A {
  function todo(uint256 index) public view returns (bool) {
    if (isIndexExists(index)) {
      // ... logic
    } else {
      revert("Index in not exist")l
    }
  }
}
```

The `isIndexExists` function works well When called directly from contract A, But in B an error occurs.

I make this call from the JS test environment in Truffle.

**Error:**
`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array `myArray` is dynamically sized. You cannot safely try to access an element with an arbitrary index using the `[]` operator, you first need to check if the index is out of bounds. Here is how you could change your function in contract `A` to achieve this:

```
function isIndexExists(uint256 index) public view returns (bool) {
  // If the index is out of bounds, then there is no such element
  if (index >= myArray.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // We know that there is an object with that index, so check its 'isExist' property
  return myArray[index].isExist;
}
```

BTW, note that when you are checking some expression that returns a boolean, you can directly return that value. You don't need the redundant if-else, which takes 5 lines compared to this approach which only takes one line of code.

Comment: Fixed with if (index >= myArray.length) .  Thanks :)))

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by either of two reasons:

1. Out of bounds: You're accessing a non-existing index of the array in the `myArray[index]` expression.
2. Missing return: You're not returning any value in the `// ... logic` section of the `todo()` function that promises to return a `bool`.

Comment: If the return statement is missing, how would the contract even compile?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Missing return doesn't throw an error during compilation. (Solc v0.8.11.; might change in later versions.)

Comment: I was not aware of this to be honest, and it's a bit unexpected I must say. I guess there should at least be a warning during compilation? But yeah, some people tend to ignore warnings, it would be a lot better if this did not compile. It sounds like a bad idea for a smart contract language, where once you deploy the contract, you cannot easily push a fix.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Yea, I agree. It seems that the compiler does give a warning if the return statement is missing in a condition (so the `todo()` function posted in the question gives a warning stating _"Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable."_)... But there's not even a warning if the whole function is missing a return statement. Hopefully they fix it in a later version.